# rnorm function but for binomial distribution

Tags: r

How can I create a list of 30 values without decimals [are either 0 or 1], that have a specific mean (example: 0.29) and a SD (example: 0.13).

I couldn't figure this out in excel or R, I hope there is a simple code for this. Thank you so much!

- Maryam

Comment: Use `rbinom` instead of `rnorm`. Of course the binomial distribution isn’t generally parametrised based on mean and standard deviation, but rather based on probability and number of experiments. And for a given number of experiments (1 in your case) and probability, the standard deviation is fixed anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much Konrad for your quick answer! Okay, now I understand why I could not find a way to do that! The reason why I wanted to do this was that I wanted to prepare a "fake dataset" that has a certain mean and standard deviation (use that for power analysis). At the moment I can only use rnorm which will output numbers that are in minus and with decimals and I wanted the values of the set to be only 0s and 1s to mimic a real dataset. I understand now why this is uncommon. thank you so much again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for binomial (0, 1),as stated by Konrad it is not based on mean and standard deviation but proportion. Even if you generate a binomial distribution the mean and the standard deviation will make less sense that the probability.

For the purpose of understanding, I have given below the means and standards deviations of the samples of possible combinations of 1 and zeros with the size 30.

```
for(n in 1:29) {
  d <- c(rep(1, 30-n), rep(0, n))
  print(c(mean(d), sd(d)))

}

[1] 0.9666667 0.1825742
[1] 0.9333333 0.2537081
[1] 0.9000000 0.3051286
[1] 0.8666667 0.3457459
[1] 0.8333333 0.3790490
[1] 0.8000000 0.4068381
[1] 0.7666667 0.4301831
[1] 0.7333333 0.4497764
[1] 0.7000000 0.4660916
[1] 0.6666667 0.4794633
[1] 0.6333333 0.4901325
[1] 0.6000000 0.4982729
[1] 0.5666667 0.5040069
[1] 0.5333333 0.5074163
[1] 0.5000000 0.5085476
[1] 0.4666667 0.5074163
[1] 0.4333333 0.5040069
[1] 0.4000000 0.4982729
[1] 0.3666667 0.4901325
[1] 0.3333333 0.4794633
[1] 0.3000000 0.4660916
[1] 0.2666667 0.4497764
[1] 0.2333333 0.4301831
[1] 0.2000000 0.4068381
[1] 0.1666667 0.3790490
[1] 0.1333333 0.3457459
[1] 0.1000000 0.3051286
[1] 0.06666667 0.25370813
[1] 0.03333333 0.18257419
```

The first column is mean and the second column is standard deviation. You could see that the lowest possible standard deviation is around 0.18

Comment: Thank you so much Mohanasundaram, the example makes things much clearer! I guess I will have to do it this way then.